# check supabase client is available

Tags: flutter, supabase

how to make sure that a supabase client instance is available for use in the Flutter project from :

```
///Supabase
await Supabase.initialize(
  url: supabaseBaseUrl,
  anonKey: supabaseBaseKey,
  authFlowType: AuthFlowType.pkce,
  authCallbackUrlHostname: 'login-callback',
  schema: 'public',
);
```

under the main()

```
final supabaseClient = Supabase.instance.client;
```

because I'm not getting any 'response' object from the

```
    checkEmailResponseData = await supabaseClient
    .from('profiles')
    .select<PostgrestList>('user_email')
    .eq('user_email', newUserEmail)
    .withConverter(
        (data) => data.map(Profiles.fromJson).toList(growable: true));
```

where Profiles is a model of the profiles table in the supabase.

I just get this error with the stack...I looked into the parsing error and used the 'withConverter()'  for no avail . any help is appreciated.

```
  I/flutter (16730): error is PostgrestException(message: <!DOCTYPE html><html 
  lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content- 
  Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" 
  content="IE=Edge"><meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"><meta 
  name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link href="/cdn- 
  cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body class="no-js"><div 
  class="main-wrapper" role="main"><div class="main-content"><noscript><div 
  id="challenge-error-title"><div class="h2"><span class="icon-wrapper"><div 
  class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div></span><span id="challenge-error- 
  text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span></div></div></noscript> 
  </div></div><script>(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId: '2',cZone: 
  "ytqwkhvjsqnq.supabase.co",cType: 'managed',cNounce: '64',cRay: 
  '81fb5c6a9bb7054f',cHash: 'd46a71266227468',cUPMDTk: "\/rest\/v1\/profiles? 
   select=user_email&user_email=eq.lapcell%40hotmail.com&__cf_chl_tk=kQ_DaQf
   I/flutter (16730): stack is #0      PostgrestBuilder._parseResponse 
   (package:postgrest/src/postgrest_builder.dart:347:7)
   I/flutter (16730): #1      PostgrestBuilder._execute 
   (package:postgrest/src/postgrest_builder.dart:202:14)
   I/flutter (16730): <asynchronous suspension>
   I/flutter (16730): #2      PostgrestBuilder.then 
   (package:postgrest/src/postgrest_builder.dart:424:24)
   I/flutter (16730): <asynchronous suspension>
```

EDIT:
yes the profiles table contains the user_email column.
The issue is that I get no response from the supabaseClient

```
   class Profiles {
     String? userEmail;
     String? userPass;

     Profiles({this.userEmail,this.userPass});


     Profiles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
       userEmail = json['user_email'];
       userPass = json['user_pass'];
      }

     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final data = Map<String, dynamic>();
         data['user_email'] = this.userEmail;
         data['user_pass'] = this.userPass;
      return data;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a `user_email` column in a `user_email` table? Also, could you edit your question and add the definition of `Profiles.fromJson`?

Comment: @dshukertjr : I have edit what you required. I tried lunch the app on the web , same resut no response .

Comment: If you remove the `withConverter`, do you get the data back, or does it still throw?

Comment: the same error...I thought it was parsing issue so I added the converter cuz it handles the parsing issues. also created the model class but with no success.

Comment: Strip down the code until the query doesn't throw an error and pin point which line is the cause.